# SUMIF staff sales bonus index based on product rank

Tags: google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I want to develop staff sales bonus index in google sheets based on product rank. So if the staff sells one brick their bonus index will be 1 and if they sell 1 cement bag, their bonus index will be 1200.

Here is the list of products with weightage of each product.

[image]

Following is the list of sales from which need to construct index.
[image]

Here is the list of staff with correctly calculated Bonus Index but with poor formula;
[image]

Here is my current formula in cell B2

```
=sumifs(K:K,H:H,A2,J:J,E$2)*F$2+sumifs(K:K,H:H,A2,J:J,E$3)*F$3+sumifs(K:K,H:H,A2,J:J,E$4)*F$4
```

As you can see there is issue with above formula that we need to add a sumifs for each product, so if there are 100+ products, this formula won't work.

Can above formula be combined to one single condition? May be possible with arrays but I am not good with arrays or may be some other way?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2=$H$2:$H$16)*(TRANSPOSE($E$2:$E$4)=$J$2:$J$16)*TRANSPOSE($F$2:$F$4)*$K$2:$K$16)
```

[image]